# What's the best way to load the proper PhoneGap file

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova

I'm developing a hybrid application using PhoneGap that will be distributed to several mobile OS.

I'm detecting the user agent in order to load the proper PhoneGap file, is there another better way of doing this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue.
My app should support only Android and all iOS issues.

This is the code I put in the head of my app:
Feel free to add more devices types if you app supports them!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/android/))
        document.write('<script charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0-droid.js"><\/script>');
    else //if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iphone/) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/ipad/))
        document.write('<script charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0-ios.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: You definitely got to read the question again. No more comments.

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure which version of Phonegap or Cordova you are using, but according to the latest docs, the `Device` allows you to take the OS's name and few more information.

Example,

`Device.platform` or `Device.name`

[Phonegap Docs for Device class](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device)

Please let me know whether it worked.

Comment: That is correct but the problem with that solution is that `Device.platform` is an object of PhoneGap framework and what I'm trying to accomplish is to create an automated way of loading the proper PhoneGap file.

Comment: read your question again: you mean to say that its a web application, to make it clear, its an on device hybrid mobile app right?

Comment: this is not correct - how can you get a reference to the object device which is a part of cordova?

Comment: @Yuki - I have linked it to Cordova library. And yes it will get the object ref for Device when you include the script in your HTML, and the answer what i given is not appropriate. I have mentioned that in the comment above. it would be fair to downvote by reading the whole conversation. Else it isn't.

Comment: @Yuki ANd the question clearly says that it is a mobile hybrid application, so my answer stands right. it is not Mobile web.

Comment: @Futur - I just did it yesterday and I managed to solve this issue. I'm posting this as a separate reply.

Answer (score -1):

the proper way is to deploy and distribute the app for different systems with different files. Have Android cordova.js when you deploy Android app, apple cordova.js when you depoy iOS app, etc.